# How to get merlin mode to work in emacs?

Tags: osx

I try to install merlin by typing "opam install merlin" in the terminal. After the installation is done, I am asked to do this, but it doesn't seem to work. The github instruction seems to be different

[image]

```el
(load "/Users/yxchng/.opam/system/share/emacs/site-lisp/tuareg-site-file")


(add-to-list 'load-path
"/Users/yxchng/.opam/system/share/emacs/site-lisp")
(require 'ocp-indent)


;; Add opam emacs directory to the load-path
(setq opam-share (substring (shell-command-to-string "opam config var
share 2> /dev/null") 0 -1))
(add-to-list 'load-path (concat opam-share "/emacs/site-lisp"))
;; Load merlin-mode
(require 'merlin)
;; Start merlin on ocaml files
(add-hook 'tuareg-mode-hook 'merlin-mode t)
(add-hook 'caml-mode-hook 'merlin-mode t)
;; Enable auto-complete
(setq merlin-use-auto-complete-mode 'easy)
;; Use opam switch to lookup ocamlmerlin binary
(setq merlin-command 'opam)
```

I added this code to .emacs but it doesn't seem to work

it gives me spurious error and says

```
/usr/local/Cellar/emacs/24.5/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs: \
/bin/bash: opam: command not found/ocamlmerlin: No such file or directory
```

*(linebreak added to prevent scrolling)*

The error is like this

[image]
How should I solve this problem?

Comment: Can you make sure the argument to `shell-command-to-string` is spelled correctly? I don't know what it should look like, but right now it looks like some bits are missing. Does it have to have a linebreak there?

Comment: @wvxvw i am not sure too, i just copy and paste from the instruction given. Thats why I need some help

Comment: "i just copy and paste from the instruction given" -- It might help to see the instructions you are trying to follow in context. Please add an appropriate link to your question.

Comment: @itsjeyd edited

Comment: Can you actually run "opam config var share" on the command line? Is "opam" in your PATH?

Comment: Now I'm almost sure there shouldn't be a linebreak (whoever made that image must've had word-wrapping enabled). But you also need to make sure `opam` is in your path as rekado pointed out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OS X does not evaluate your shell configuration for GUI applications.  Hence, your Emacs runs with a different `$PATH` than your shell, and thus can't find the `opam` executable.

The [exec-path-from-shell](https://github.com/purcell/exec-path-from-shell) package helps you to work around this issue.  Simply install the package with `M-x package-install` and then add the following to your init file:

```
(when (memq window-system '(mac ns))
  (exec-path-from-shell-initialize))
```

Likewise, I'd recommend you to install Merlin via `M-x package-install RET merlin`, because that makes all the `load-path` management in your init file redundant, and reduces your OPAM configuration to:

```
(add-hook 'tuareg-mode-hook #'merlin-mode)
(add-hook 'caml-mode-hook #'merlin-mode) ; If you really like to use Caml Mode

(with-eval-after-load 'merlin
  (setq merlin-command 'opam))
```